# Apache Camel - Possibility to insert a line in csv file

Tags: groovy, apache-camel

Here below i export sql result data with Apache Camel.
What i want to do is once sql result is saved in csv and insert the column names in the first line in csv.
Is there possiblity to do it with Apache Camel or groovy ?

```
<!-- Column names -->
<setBody>
    <groovy>"Name|Departement|Age|\n"</groovy>
</setBody>

<!-- Saving column names in csv file -->
<to uri="file:{{export.customer.dir}}?fileName=exportCustomer.csv&amp;charset=utf-8" />

<!-- Select sql -->
<to uri="sql:{{export.customer.select}}?dataSource=customerDataSource" />


<marshal>
    <csv delimiter="|" />
</marshal>

<!-- Saving sql result in the same csv -->
<to uri="file:{{export.customer.dir}}?fileName=exportCustomer.csv&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;fileExist=Append" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could either use the attribute `header` like you did with `delimiter` or you can set the option directly in the camel-component (if your headers are always the same): `camel.dataformat.csv.header` (in your application.properties).

More information can be found under: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/csv-dataformat.html

Example (but I did not have the time to try it myself):

```
      <unmarshal>
        <csv delimiter="|" useMaps="true">
          <header>MyOrderId</header>
          <header>MyItem</header>
          <header>MyAmount</header>
        </csv>
      </unmarshal>
```

Comment: I cannot use 'header' got a msg error -> 'Attribute 'header' is not allowed to appear in element 'csv'

Comment: `<csv delimiter="|"><header>Name</header><header>Department</header><header>Age</header></csv>` - https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-csv/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/dataformat/csv/CsvUnmarshalMapLineSpringTest-context.xml

Comment: According to the answer from @Bedla I updated my answer. Try with that pls.

Comment: i have an error "Element 'csv' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty" using <header></hearder>
The reason why i generate the column names seperately was the csv option such as headerDisabled etc didn't work..
If i could generate csv file with column header and data at the same time, it would be perfect.

Comment: `<header></hearder>` is that the exact value you used? If so, there is a typing error in the closing element and also the element is not allowed to be empty. So it should be `<header>Value</header>`

Comment: I used with value `<header>Name</header><header>Department</header><header>Age</header>`